# MongoError: Unsupported projection option - when using $elemMatch

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a subject model:

```
const subjectSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  syllabus: {
    currentChapter: {
      heading: String,
      topics: [String],
    },
    chapters: [
      {
        heading: String,
        topics: [String],
      },
    ],
  },
});
```

I am trying to find a document that corresponds to a particular id. So, I can use:

```
const subject = await Subject.find({ _id: id });
```

But now I want that in the `chapters` array I get only that document that has the heading property equal to "H 1". So I am using $elemMatch (projection).

```
const subject = await Subject.find(
    { _id: id },
    { syllabus: { chapters: { $elemMatch: { heading: "H 1" } } } }
);
```

But this is throwing an error.

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: Unsupported projection option: syllabus: { chapters: { $elemMatch: { heading: "H 
1" } } }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot use `elemMatch` with nested fields.

###### 1) Query the docs that have heading equal to `"H1"`.

`Subject.find({_id: id, "syllabus.chapters.heading": "H1"})`: This will give all the docs where the `chapters` array contains at least one object with `heading` as `"H1"`.

But, here `chapters` array will contain all the objects present in it.

###### 2) Filter only the matching objects (first matching) from the query condition using the `$` positional operator.

> The positional $ operator limits the contents of an array to return the first element that matches the query condition on the array. [Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/)

`Subject.find({_id: id, "syllabus.chapters.heading": "H1"}, {"syllabus.chapters.$1": 1})`: This will only keep the first matching object where `heading` is equal to `"H1"`.

Working Solution: [Here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kMy8afDPqxb)

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the `$elemMatch` condition in the second argument of the `find` function. You need to move it to the object in the first argument, at the same level as `_id: id`, and change it to `"syllabus.chapters": { $elemMatch: { heading: "H 1" } }`.

Here's a working [MongoPlayground link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9LP1yNSzeKd)

Comment: I want that in the `chapters` array I get only that entry which has the heading property equal to "H 1". But in this I will get all entries.